# How to make Vimeo object?

Tags: php

I do not know why I cannot make an object from the following class.
The error that I am getting is:

"Class 'Vimeo' not found ".

Please could someone advise me on where I am going wrong?

My php:

```
require_once('Vimeo/Vimeo.php');

$client_id = '1234';
$client_secret = 'abcd';

$vimeo = new Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret, $access_token = null);
```

Vimeo Class:

```
 namespace Vimeo;

use Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoUploadException;
use Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoRequestException;

 class Vimeo
{
const ROOT_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.vimeo.com';
const AUTH_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize';
const ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = '/oauth/access_token';
const CLIENT_CREDENTIALS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = '/oauth/authorize/client';
const REPLACE_ENDPOINT = '/files';
const VERSION_STRING = 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json; version=3.2';
const USER_AGENT = 'vimeo.php 1.0; (http://developer.vimeo.com/api/docs)';
const CERTIFICATE_PATH = '/certificates/vimeo-api.pem';

private $_client_id = null;
private $_client_secret = null;
private $_access_token = null;

protected $_curl_opts = array();
protected $CURL_DEFAULTS = array();

/**
 * Creates the Vimeo library, and tracks the client and token information.
 *
 * @param string $client_id Your applications client id. Can be found on developer.vimeo.com/apps
 * @param string $client_secret Your applications client secret. Can be found on developer.vimeo.com/apps
 * @param string $access_token Your applications client id. Can be found on developer.vimeo.com/apps or generated using OAuth 2.
 */
public function __construct($client_id, $client_secret, $access_token = null)
{
    $this->_client_id = $client_id;
    $this->_client_secret = $client_secret;
    $this->_access_token = $access_token;
    $this->CURL_DEFAULTS = array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        //Certificate must indicate that the server is the server to which you meant to connect.
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        CURLOPT_CAINFO => realpath(__DIR__ .'/../..') . self::CERTIFICATE_PATH
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `new Vimeo\Vimeo(...)`, I mean, everywhere you use Vimeo class, you should say `Vimeo\Vimeo`.

This is because of the php namespace. You can google it for further information.

Hope it works!